# Connecting a battery lead without soldering

Tags: batteries, connector, contact, spring

[image]

I have this battery with two leads, much like a capacitor. Due to several constraints (size, labor, etc) i am looking for a way to mount it without soldering. Simply pushing it in place would be great for the assembly process.

Is there any type of SMT connector or spring for that? Maybe something else.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid a wave solder or hand solder process? It's the only through hole component? SMT is asking for trouble on a component with that much leverage. There are pin receptacles in through-hole, SMT, and press-fit varieties but they are expensive.

Comment: i want no soldering at all. the whole thing will be wrapped inside a small plastic enclosure, a bit like an earbud, so leverage is not a problem. i would expect a sort of a sheet metal spring going inside a slot hole. but it feels something too special to be of-the-shelf smt part

Comment: A female pin header might work, what’s the diameter of the pins?

Comment: There are pin sockets [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hUkr.png). Would that be okay? (You would need to find a match, of course, in terms of pin diameter.)

Comment: Pin receptacles are what you want. Like from Milli-max.

Comment: There are fuse holders with that pitch for small radial fuses with good grip